# Cannot load jar-with-dependencies on Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have an application created in Maven as a complete jar which runs on most platforms (Windows, Unix, some Mac) but not on Mac lion/10.6, failing with the error

```
java –jar jumbo-converters-crystal-cif-0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 0151.cif 0151.cml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ?jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ?jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

UPDATE: the MANIFEST.MF contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: pm286
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Main-Class: org.xmlcml.cml.converters.cif.CIF2CMLConverter
```

SOLUTION: @Charlie is right. This error occurred in a class. Most delegates had no problems. The "culprit" is Powerpoint. I was required to make my material available as Powerpoint (not my normal practice) and it had "helpfully" converted HYPHEN-MINUS (U+002D) to EN_DASH. Most delegates typed this normally, but some cut and pasted the corrupt command.

Comment: Extract your manifest from the JAR file and include it in the question please.

Comment: Thanks. I will do so. May take a little time and be quite large...

Comment: @Perception is this the file you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the command you're using to execute

```
java –jar jumbo-converters-crystal-cif-0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 0151.cif 0151.cml
```

is wrong... it should be:

```
java -jar jumbo-converters-crystal-cif-0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 0151.cif 0151.cml
```

(It might not be apparent but the first one is an ['EN DASH' (U+2013)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) before the `jar` and the second is a [hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm).)

Comment: Brilliant - I should have thought of this. I was running a class and most of the delegates had typed '-' correctly.